# Mongoose saving for populate

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

I'm new to Mongoose and Nodejs developement in general and I've got a bit of confusion around how to properly set up saving my records. Here are my two schemas:

**Download**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var downloadSchema = Schema({
    title        : String,
    description  : String,
    _project      : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Download', downloadSchema);
```

**Project**

```
...

var projectSchema = Schema({
    name         : String,
    url          : String,
    pwd          : String,
    _downloads   : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Download' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

This appears to be working correctly. The documentation explains my use-case of saving a download and linking a project, but I'm not sure how to properly populate the `Project._downloads`. Here's what I've done:

**Express route handler:**

```
function createDownload(req, res) {

    // the Project Id is passed in the req.body as ._project
    var dldata = req.body;

    Project.findOne({ _id : dldata._project }, function(err, project) {
        var dload = new Download(dldata);


        dload.save( function (err, download) {

            project._downloads.push(download._id);
            project.save( function(err){
                var msg = {};
                if(err) {
                    msg.status = 'error';
                    msg.text = err;
                }else {
                    msg.status = 'success';
                    msg.text = 'Download created successfully!';
                }

                res.json(msg);
            });

        });
    });
}
```

This seems overcomplicated to me. Am I supposed to be manually `push`ing to the `._downloads` array, or is that something Mongoose is supposed to handle internally based on the schema? Is there a better way to achieve it so that I can do:

```
Download.find().populate('_project').exec( ...
```

as well as:

```
Project.findOne({_id : _projectId}).populate('_downloads').exec( ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) there are 2 ways to add subdocs to the parent object:

1) by using the push() method

2) by using the create() method

So I think that your code can be a bit simplified by eliminating the operation of saving a new Download item:

```
function createDownload(req, res) {
    var dldata = req.body;

    Project.findOne({ _id : dldata._project }, function(err, project) {
        // handle error

        project._downloads.push(dldata);

        project.save(function(err) {
            // handle the result
        });
    });
}
```

or

```
function createDownload(req, res) {
    var dldata = req.body;

    Project.findOne({ _id : dldata._project }, function(err, project) {
        // handle error

        project._downloads.create(dldata);

        project.save(function(err) {
            // handle the result
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Once I modified my Project schema for `._downloads` to: `_downloads : [Download.schema]` it worked like a charm. I didn't know enough to even look at subdocs, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction as well.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!